# Help Partitioning my Hard Drive

Tags: partitioning

I am doing a fresh install of Ubuntu on an external hard drive so I can carry it around with me and use it on my Chromebook. (This is my first time doing ANYTHING with Linux)

I can make the USB installer from Windows and have that just fine. But, when I go into the Ubuntu setup and click 'something else' to partition my external USB 3.0 HDD things start acting up. For some reason every time I create a partition an extra little thing of free space that is 11 or 13 megabits in size keeps popping up.

In all the instructional videos I have watched this did not happen. But I kept creating partitions like the videos said. Once I was done I clicked install and it gave me a message saying that it would be a bad idea to install rn because it would not be safe so I clicked og back and looked up the message online.

It said to change my ext4 partition to xfs, so I did. Then it installed. But when I tried to boot from the hard drive it took me back to the install/try Ubuntu thing again. So I restarted again and then it gave me a select boot device black screen with white text.

Comment: Logically the disk breaks up in to certain chunks, the partitions like to start on certain boundaries, not within a "chunk", so if you pick a particular partition size there's often a bit left over. Like a book having a gap between the next chapter starts. `gparted` or similar will let you fix that later (add the space to the partition to its left). The rest of it is probably to do with secure boot? https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/29073

Comment: Might just be you need to remove the install media before rebooting?

Comment: I have already checked in my bios. There is no secure boot option. I looked online and it says that secure boot is automatically disabled. I have msi click bios 5 on a x470 gaming plus board. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me what partitions you use so I can try it your way?

Comment: I have never seen the installer or gparted suggest XFS, and I do not think you can use XFS as / (root) only as a data partition. You typically need either an ESP for UEFI boot or a bios_grub for BIOS boot, and /. If larger drive often better to keep / as 25 or 30GB and use separate /home and/or /data partition(s). But too many partitions may make management of space more difficult. Installer now uses swap file, so not swap partition required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace